# session variables is not working while coming to same page again

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-7

Hi I am trying to have an add to cart link in drupal views with every items displayed and change it to remove from cart on clicking it. and achieved up-to this. and ids of selected items are getting storing in session . if I close the view and open it again I want my selected items link to be remove from cart but its not happening.

views-view-field--iiteneries--nid.tpl.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["iteneries"][$output])){
?>
<a id="iteneries_<?php print $output; ?>" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ccc" onclick="remove_from_cart(<?php print $output; ?>,'iteneries')">Remove from cart</a>
<?php }
else{ 
?>
<a id="iteneries_<?php print $output; ?>" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ccc" onclick="add_to_cart(<?php print $output; ?>,'iteneries')">Add to cart</a>
<?php }
```

?>

Thanks in advance for any help....

Comment: Try this: https://www.google.ro/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=drupal+session&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=7G4GUcqTLIqItQb1toHgAg

Comment: Sounds like you already have some html output before this fragment is displayed, correct? If it is like that, session_start(); won't work and could cause the error

Comment: above that I just have comments will that affect it?

Comment: I have a drupal view and i am using this views-view-field--iiteneries--nid.tpl.php file to just override the particular field

Comment: @VladPreda I am new to drupal actually i have done evrything in coding for creating the session variables so how can i use this module?

Comment: is there some one who can help me out???

Comment: Yes, the session API I linked above. I though the google link was enough to make you at least check out my search. The API you needed was the 3rd of 4th link ( http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/7 )

Comment: _drupal_session_read($_SESSION["iteneries"][$output]);  should i use like this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You are not using the session in Drupal in correct way. You don't have to include session_start() to use session as far as I know. Drupal automatically does that for you. 
Secondly, check if your data is being stored in the session variable or not, 
just us `print_r($_SESSION)`, `dpm($_SESSION)` (if u are using Devel module)  to debug the session variable. If you don't see your information being stored in the $_SESSION variable then, check in the add to cart logic where you are adding the values in the $_SESSION variables.